# Nemo right-click action for filenames with special characters

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager, cinnamon

How can I open files whose name contains sharps / hashes `#`
from the Cinnamon Nemo right-click context menu?

A Nemo action e.g. `/usr/share/nemo/actions/unzap.nemo_action`
which contains the line `Exec=unzap "%F"` will open most files,
but fail to escape filenames which contain a `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exec=<open.py "unzap" %F>` instead of `Exec=unzap "%F"` in the `unzap.nemo_action`.

The unescape the backslashes in `open.py` as follows:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3 -OOt

import sys
import subprocess

command = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2].replace("\ "," ")

subprocess.run([command, filename])
```